# Autolayout is breaking when UITableViewCell is scrolled especially for UIImageView

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I need UITableViewCell in a dynamic height depends on the content length.

This is a prototype cell

[image: Prototype cell]

And the content shows fine when first loaded like this

[image: Works fine initially]

But when I scroll the UITableView, the cell's content breaks like this, especially for UIImageView.

[image: Breaks]

In the implementation of the cell, I only used `setImage` and `setText` method.

What seems the problem? Or, is there another way to set each cell's height differently after `viewDidLoad`?

** Edit: this is my implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NotificationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"notification"];
    if(!cell) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"NotificationCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"notification"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"notification"];
    }

    [cell setContent:[notifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}
```

And `setContent` in NotificationCell.m has only `setText` and `setImage`

Comment: configured dynamic height steps properly ???

Comment: put  [cell layoutIfNeeded] before return cell

Comment: Can you show the cell file, and tableView cellForRowAtIndex path method?

Comment: @iamirzhan I edited the post but I think I've done this properly.

Comment: @Sh_Khan `[cell layoutIfNeeded]` didn't helped :(

Comment: post code in cellForRow

Comment: @Sh_Khan I edited the post

Comment: @AlfredWoo yeah, thanks! It may be stupid suggestion, but did you create your outlet to you imageView? Because UITableView already has imageView property, and it seems like you set the image to that imageView, because it is in the left side of the cell.

Comment: @iamirzhan Oh wow that was the problem! The name of outlet was just imageView and changing the name fixed the problem!

Comment: @AlfredWoo Cool! I have post the answer. Please accept it for others.

Comment: @iamirzhan Of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the tableView already has an imageView property and it is on the left side of the cell, you set the image to that imageView. You should rename the outlet of your custom imageView. So, it should be not called imageView, give the other name for it.